# Where can I find good documentation on OpenXML

Tags: .net, powerpoint, openxml

I'm looking to create powerpoint file in OpenXML.

I'm looking to use the following features

- Bind bits of the page to an xml file.
  For example, one tag would be bound
  to the name field of an xml file. The
  plan is to simple drop the xml file
  in the right folder, zip up the
  template, and rename the file the
  proper extension and have it just
  work.
- I'm looking to have repeating
  sections of the code. I want the
  template to work like a datagrid. For
  example, I want
  `<item><child><name>a</name></child><child><name>b</name></child><child><name>c</name></child></item>` in the xml file to create A B C in
  the correct format on the source
  file.
- I want to be able to access vbscript
  to put conditions into the template
  so ceratin items are displayed in
  certain times. I want to change
  colors based on conditions as well.

Is all of this possible? Where can i find documentation in order to do this using the OpenXML API or whatever toolkit is appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a  look at this [Videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/OpenXML) and  the [basics of OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx). Since you may be looking for topics with the tags and generating  diferent types of files here's a more [specific one](http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/category/1007.aspx). Check around to see if you find something meeting your needs.

Comment: Do you know where I can find any actual examples of binding with PowerPoint? Direct binding tags via xpath, like word uses don't seem to be supported and macros are disabled by default by many of my users, which makes VBScript a pain. I'm trying to avoid any business logic aside from plopping an xml file into the package when my server processes a template.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example of replacing Pictures in a slide maybe that can be a start
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727373.aspx